# How to read excel in python from user input

Tags: python, excel, input

I have an excel file that looks like this:

Bob | 15

Joe | 25

Tim | 19

I'm trying to write a code so that if the user inputs the name bob, it will print 15.. or if the user inputs Joe, it will print 25 etc

I can't figure out how to get python to read an input string and match it to the cell in excel

Comment: can you provide what codes have you written so far?

Answer (score 0):

Through pandas you can do this free feel to ask.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
user_input = input()
value = df[df['name_column'] == user_input]
print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it using only Pandas

```
import pandas as pd

# to read the Excel into Python:
df = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx")

# to get input name from user
input = input()

# to get output id from input name
output = df[df.name == input].id

# to print result
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

just follow these steps buddy to open  excel in python

```
import xlrd 
  

tt = open("file name ") 
  
#opening excel
ex = xlrd.open_workbook(tt) 
sheet = ex.sheet_by_index(0) 
  
# for row 0 and column 0 
print(sheet.cell_value(0, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to consider what if the name user input doesn't exist.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None)

name = input('Input name: ')

try:
    value = df[df[0] == name][1].values[0]
    print(f'value of {name} is: {value}')
except IndexError:
    print('Name not found')
```

Output 1:

```
Input name: Bob
value of Bob is: 15
```

Output 2:

```
Input name: Chris
Name not found
```